# How to merge the output of an Observable that emits Observables without breaking the operator chain?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, couchbase-java-api

The context is using Couchbase to implement a REST CRUD service on a 2-level document store. The data model is an index document pointing to zero or more item documents. The index document is retrieved as an Observable using an asynchronous get. This is followed by a .flatMap() that retrieves zero or more IDs for each item document. The async get returns an Observable, so now the Observable I'm creating is Observable>. I want to chain a .merge() operator that will take  "an Observable that emits Observables, and will merge their output into the output of a single Observable" to quote the ReactiveX documentation :) Then I will .subscribe() to that single Observable to retrieve item documents. The .merge() operator has a many signatures, but I can't figure out how to use it in a chain of operators as follows:

```
bucket
.async()
.get(id)
.flatMap(
    document -> {

        JsonArray itemArray = (JsonArray) document.content().get("item");
        //  create Observable that gets and emits zero or more 
        // Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>> ie. bucket.async().gets
        Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>> items =
            Observable.create(observer -> {
                try {
                    if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                itemArray.forEach(
                    (jsonObject) -> {
                        String itemId = ((JsonObject)jsonObject).get("itemid").toString();
                        observer.onNext( 
                            bucket.async().get(itemId)
                        );
                    }
                    }
                );
                        observer.onCompleted();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    observer.onError(e);
                }
            }
        );          
        return items;
    },
    throwable -> {
        //  error handling omitted...
        return Observable.empty();
    },
    () -> {
        //  on complete processing omitted...
        return null;
    }
)
.merge( ???????? )
.subscribe( 
    nextItem -> {
        //  do something with each item document...
    },
    throwable -> {
        //  error handling omitted...
    },
    () -> {
         //  do something else...
    }
);
```

EDIT:

You probably guessed I'm a reactive newbie. The answer from @akarnokd helped me realise what I was trying to do was dumb. The solution is to merge the emissions from the items `Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>>` inside the `document` closure and return the result of that. This emits the resulting `JsonDocuments` from the `flatMap`:

```
bucket
.async()
.get(id)
.flatMap(
    document -> {

        JsonArray itemArray = (JsonArray) document.content().get("item");
        //  create Observable that gets and emits zero or more 
        // Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>> ie. bucket.async().gets
        Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>> items =
            Observable.create(observer -> {
                try {
                    if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                itemArray.forEach(
                    (jsonObject) -> {
                        String itemId = ((JsonObject)jsonObject).get("itemid").toString();
                        observer.onNext( 
                            bucket.async().get(itemId)
                        );
                    }
                    }
                );
                        observer.onCompleted();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    observer.onError(e);
                }
            }
        );          
        return Observable.merge(items);
    },
    throwable -> {
        //  error handling omitted...
        return Observable.empty();
    },
    () -> {
        //  on complete processing omitted...
        return null;
    }
)
.subscribe( 
    nextItem -> {
        //  do something with each item document...
    },
    throwable -> {
        //  error handling omitted...
    },
    () -> {
         //  do something else...
    }
);
```

Tested and works :)

Comment: So currently you get `Observable<Observable<JsonDocument>>` but want to get `Observable<JsonDocument>`?

Comment: yes, thats correct. If I started the chain with a merge, I could give it an Observable<Observable<T>>. As http://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd notes in his answer, rxJava does not have a way of doing this within a chain of operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to expressive limits of Java, we can't have a parameterless `merge()` operator that can be applied on an `Observble<Observable<T>>`. It would require extension methods such as in C#.

The next best thing is to do an identity `flatMap`:

```
// ...
.flatMap(document -> ...)
.flatMap(v -> v)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: If I use `.flatMap()` then I would need to use `.toBlocking().first()` or equivalent in the `onNext` to retrieve the `JsonDocument` from the Observable? My implementation currently uses `bucket.async().get(itemId).toBlocking().first()` in the items Observable. I was trying to do this non-blocking. Or maybe I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: You asked about how to do fluent merge(). It has nothing to do with whether the stream or the value in the identity flatMap are async or not. How do you want to consume the flattened values?

Comment: Your answer is correct. My async requirement is not what I originally asked, so I'm marking as the correct answer. I now have a solution to the async part so I will edit my question to show the solution to that...

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toList()` to collect all emitted items into one list. I've not tested it but what about something like this:

```
bucket.async()
  .get(id)
  .flatmap(document -> { return Observable.from((JsonArray)document.content().get("item")})
  .flatMap(bucket::get)
  .toList()
  .subscribe(results -> /* list of documents */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This may work, but I now understand how `merge()` works and will edit my question with the soluition I am using